# Escape variable for echo in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable $MOH in Bash which may contain words beginning with minus (-).

I don't want echo to interpret these words as parameters.

For most commands I do it like this:

```
cmd -- $MOH
```

But echo does not support --.

So I get a problem in this example:

```
MOH=-n
echo $MOH
```

Echo thinks -n is a parameter. But as I said I want to echo the variable as it is.
(Please note that the value of $MOH is not known to me.)

So my question is: How to escape a variable for use in echo?

Also the escape function should be aware of future parameters in echo which are not known yet.

**Edit**:
Thank you for editing. The question was already asked and the solution is to use printf instead of echo.

Comment: This is addressed in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451742/14122 in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Also see [Why is printf better then echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [unix.se], and [the POSIX standard for echo](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which itself recommends using printf instead (see in particular the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

Answer (score 3):

It is a known limitation of `echo`, and actually it is better not to use `echo` in the first place but rather `printf` (see below).

Also, beware that there are some quoting issues in your command, one should always use `"$MOH"` instead of `$MOH`. Otherwise, "bad things happen" if the variable contains spaces or `*` characters… For details on this issue, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Hence the command:

```sh
MOH='-n'
printf '%s\n' "$MOH"
```